# Qt slot with default argument 

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a block of spin controls which change individual elements of an array
Rather than having separate receiver slot functions, I wanted to just specify which control sent the message in the signal

You can do this with a QSignalMapper - but is there anyway of doing it simply as below?

```
spin0 = new QDoubleSpinBox;
connect(spin0,SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)),this,SLOT(handler(0,double));

spin1 = new QDoubleSpinBox;
connect(spin1,SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)),this,SLOT(handler(1,double));
....

private slot:
void handler(int element,double value);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From any slot handler you can can use [sender()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender) to get a pointer to the object that sent the signal. Then you can use the [objectName()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#objectName-prop) property to communicate any further identifying information.

Comment: But then the reciever function needs to know a lot of details of the gui - ie. have access to all the spincontrol objects

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. If you set the object name on each spin control to be "0", "1", etc. then in your handler you can use `sender()->objectName().toInt()` to achieve what you are stating above . The handler doesn't need to know anything more than a `QObject` sent a signal. Just to claify, `sender()` is a function of the object in which `handler()` resides. No need to know about all of the spin controls.

Comment: ok using the object name, yes that's a good soln. I was thinking of comparing the sender() with the spin0 ptr which coupled the gui to the handler rather too closely!

Comment: Ah, yeah, that would be a tight coupling :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, at least not using that syntax ... the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros turn their arguments into strings which are then parsed and used by the Qt runtime to look-up the associated functions and/or class methods in the tables created by `moc` during the pre-processing phase of compilation.  So if you encoded a default argument into the `SLOT` macro, then that's not a valid function signature that can be used by Qt for run-time lookup of the actual slot function in the `moc`-generated function tables.